# Possible to set values of RegEx?

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if its possible to set my "set of values" to put to RegEx (Or any other methods if there is)...?

Here's what I need to do...

```
string myString = "Hello<<Prefix>> <<surname>>!!";
```

**My PROBLEM:**

I need to replace those strings with "<<....>>" to a value in my database.

I'm thinking of getting all those "<<....>>" and put it in a List but if you have other simpler/easier way, please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, you want to get all values between `<<` and `>>`?

Comment: [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) or [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @SonerGönül - those with "<<...>>" are tags I need to get in order for me to know what value/s should I replace it with. For example, I need to replace that "<<Prefix>>" with a "Mr." -> (this is inside my database) and "<<surname>>" with "Smith".

Comment: @RGraham - yes, Im planning to use String.Replace once I get all those "<<...>>"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you need to use `String.Format` method. Given:

```
public class User
{
    public string Prefix {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
}
```

The output should be constructed like:

```
var message = String.Format("Hello {0} {1}!!", user.Prefix, user.Surname);
```

Comment: This is nice but not for my case... What @Prescott said in his answer is right. Its TEMPLATING... Im creating an email template with tags "<<...>>" then when I'm gonna send that template, Im gonna replace those tags with values in the database

Answer (score 0):

A keyword you might want to search on is templating. One way to do it would be something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
// Populate the dictionary with your key values
dict.Add("PREFIX", "Mr");
dict.Add("SURNAME", "Prescott");

string myString = "Hello<<PREFIX>> <<SURNAME>>!!";
foreach(item in dict)
{
    myString = myString.Replace("<<" + item.Key + ">>", item.Value);
}
```

Note this is a bit naive, it will loop through an entire dictionary you load even if there is only one element to replace.

Comment: I like @RePierre's answer better for your question. But if you need flexibility in templating (for example an email message might use first name, last name, in different orders etc) I think my solution is more flexible.

Comment: Actually, yours might work for me. Its just that it will loop all throughout the string. But will still try this one

Comment: This is good but I think you should use `Regex`'s replace, instead of `String`'s

Comment: @AlirezNoori - not arguing, just curious, why do you say that?